# Difference between drawn and haggard

Tags: writing-style, collocation, literature, redundancy

In the novel *Rage of Angels* by Sidney Sheldon, we read:

> She watched Adam now as he sat at his desk looking drawn and haggard.

Dictionaries such as Oxford and Cambridge are showing the same or similar meanings for both words. Then why did Sidney Sheldon, one of the best selling writers, use them together?

I guess it might be to make the scene more effective, but is it so?

Comment: Please show definitions from say four different dictionaries, commenting on any differences.

Comment: Partly the writer added ***and haggard*** because ***drawn*** on its own normally has completely different connotations, so ***...and** [near-synonym]* makes it easier for the reader to immediately grasp the reference.

Comment: ... So much so that [*He looks drawn **and** (haggard, tired, whatever)*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28looks+drawn%29-%28looks+drawn+and%29%2Clooks+drawn+and&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28looks%20drawn%29%20-%20%28looks%20drawn%20and%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clooks%20drawn%20and%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C(looks%20drawn)%20-%20(looks%20drawn%20and)%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clooks%20drawn%20and%3B%2Cc0) is actually just as common as the "bare" form *He looks drawn.*

Comment: ...but there's nothing wrong with repetition / tautology in English anyway. It's a perfectly natural feature of the language.

Comment: I would take "best selling" as an indication of much. See the case of *50 Shades v. Literature*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks for your lucid answer

Comment: @jimm101 I honestly didn't get you

Comment: It's just a comment that a "best selling" author doesn't at all indicate that the author writes well, or follows all the rules. They may just tell interesting stories.

Comment: @jimm101: In the long run, best-selling authors pretty much ***define*** "the rules".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Agreed. Might be true for J. K. Rowling, let's hope it's unlikely for E. J. James. im sure smth like this will ok someday 2 when we end the 2500 yo tyranny of punctuation

Comment: @jimm101: I think as well as making some (totally unnecessary, imho) changes to *vocabulary*, for American editions of the Harry Potter books, they insisted on adding dozens of (also, unnecessary) ***commas***. So it's not "**us**" (Brits) standing in the way of "progress" here, it's the **US**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitions of *drawn* and *haggard* are indeed similar; *haggard* even appears in *drawn*'s definition on wiktionary!

[**drawn**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drawn#Adjective) (adj.)

1. Appearing tired and unwell, as from stress; **haggard**
2. Of a game: undecided; having no definite winner and loser

[**haggard**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/haggard#Adjective) (adj.)

1. Looking exhausted, worried, or poor in condition
2. Wild or untamed

Both mean tired-looking, but, in my mind, the connotations of their use differ in the reason why the person looks tired.

I read *drawn* as describing the physical manifestation of psychological tension.  As a [ductile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ductility) metal may be [drawn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drawing_(manufacturing)) by force into wire, so may a person's psyche be drawn thin by anxiety.

*Haggard*, however, implies to me exposure to the elements, per the second definition given above.  To be *haggard* is to be roughed-up by life, [wizened](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wizened) by the passage of time, like a [hag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hag).  I think that a person can appear *haggard* without an underlying psychological burden, albeit "worried" appears in the first definition.